# javascript .hide on click event trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<header data-role="header">
    <h1> TEA TIME </h1>
    <a href="#home" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-top ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-notext">back</a>
</header>
<h1>Takes 3 Minutes</h1>
<p id="timedisp">120 Sec</p>
<div class="clock">

</div>

<a href="#" id="start">Start</a>
<a href="#" id="reset">Reset</a>

</section>
```

the below is the html that controls my timer

```
function greenTea(){
```

Set The Duration
        var duration = 120;

```
Insert the duration into the div with a class of clock
    $(".clock").html(duration + " sec");  


Create a countdown interval

    var countdown = setInterval(function () {

        // subtract one from duration and test to see
        // if duration is still above zero
        if (--duration) {
            // Update the clocks's message
            $(".clock").html(duration + " sec");
        // Otherwise
        } else {

             // Clear the countdown interval
            clearInterval(countdown);
            // set a completed message
            $(".clock").html("End Your Steep");  

        }

    // Run interval every 1000ms 
    }, 1000);

};


$("a#start").click(greenTea)

Why is the below not working? I am trying to get my p#timedisp to disappear when I click the a#start link.

$("p#timedisp").hide(("a#start").click()); 

$('#reset').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: you need to put more code for me to be able to help

Comment: More details about your HTML, JS is necessary to answer this question.  Please read our Help section on how to create an  MCVE
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.
You will get faster, better help from the community that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery should be:

```
$('#start').click(function(){
    $('#timedisp').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something along the lines of this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("p#timedisp").on('click', function() {
    //$("a#start").hide();

    alert('do hide');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="timedisp">120 Sec</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you included jQuery library this should work

```
<a id="start" href="#">CLICK ME</a>
<p id="timedisp">120 Sec</p>


<script>
$(function() { // DOM is now ready

    $("#start").click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default anchor behavior
        $("#timedisp").hide(); 
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
 $('#start').on("click",function(){
     document.getElementById('timedisp').style.display = 'none';
      //post code
    })
```